# How can I add a custom compiler flag that is not directly supported by node-gyp?

Tags: c++, node-gyp, gyp

I have an MSVC project that is set up with Gyp.
I have looked at the source of gyp and there I didn't find any reference to `/Zm` flags.

Where can I put `/Zm200` in the gyp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a `msvs_settings` dictionary in a GYP target for MSVC:

```
        'msvs_settings': {
            'VCCLCompilerTool': { 'AdditionalOptions': ['/Zm200'], },
        },
```